# Travelling to Italy by train from Spain

Tags: italy, event-based-effects, covid-19

Apparently flights toward and from Italy are being cancelled, I presume this is due to Covid-19 spread. Is still possible to enter from and to Italy by other means from Spain? train?

Comment: Why would anyone want to?

Comment: Sometimes things are not up to what you want, but what you HAVE to do @guest

Comment: What is your reason for travel? There are some exceptions from the travel bans currently in effect in Italy.

Comment: Austria and Slovenia have announced the closure of their borders with Italy. Other countries may follow. This is a rapidly evolving situation and what is true today may not be true tomorrow.

Answer (score 5):

According to multiple sources:

> Italy’s 60-million people will only be able to travel for work, medical reasons or emergencies until April 3 2020. All schools and universities, which were closed nationwide last week until March 15 2020, will now not reopen before next month. [[Reuters]](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-italy-conte/movement-restricted-across-italy-in-new-coronavirus-crackdown-pm-conte-idUSKBN20W2XZ)

So you are going to need permission and a good reason to do any travelling at all in Italy for the next few weeks. You should be aware that you are likely to face quarantine on your return.

Comment: If I have understood the new restrictions correctly, you do not need a permission in advance, but have to carry (or fill out if requested) a 'self declaration' describing the reason why you are entitled to travel. The exception 'travel for work' is anyway rather broad and unspecific.

Answer (score 0):

At time of writing, information is quite confusing.

- Thello has stopped they services Marseille-Milan and Paris-Milan-Venice.
- SNCF has stopped some Paris-Torino-Milan services, but apparently not all.
- There are apparently still services along the coast up to Ventimiglia (the town on the French-Italian border), as well as internal services within Italy.

It's unclear what checks or restrictions (if any) there are when trying to enter or exit Italy.

Note that you could end up in a situation where you manage to enter Italy, but either cannot travel within Italy or cannot exit it.

The whole situation could also change at any time.